# Using Devexpress MVC TreeList to list order totals by client

Tags: linq, devexpress-mvc

I'm trying to implement a DevExpress MVC TreeList that shows a list of clients as the first level of the hierarchy. But when you open one client, the second level must show a list of related orders with their OrderTotal for each order.

I'm trying to base myself on the demo at http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxTreeListDemos/DataBinding/DataBinding which is similar to what I'm looking for. I'm using the Northwind database as an example.

The model that the TreeList must be based on has to be specific in that it has to have the following structure (maybe I'm wrong on this):

CustomerId, 
Order.CustomerId,
CustomerName,
OrderTotal,
OrderDate,
ShipCity

The second one has to be the "ParentId" in order to satisfy the hierarchy structure.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
       [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult OrderTreeListPartial()
    {
        var model = db.Orders.GroupBy(o => o.Customer)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                CustomerId = group.Key.CustomerID,
                ParentId = group.Select(g=>g.CustomerID),
                CustomerName = group.Key.CompanyName,
                OrderTotal = group.Sum(g => g.OrderTotal),
                OrderDate = group.Select(g => g.OrderDate),
                City = group.Select(g => g.ShipCity)
            });

        return PartialView("_OrderTreeListPartial", model);
    }
```

And I have the following in my _OrderTreeListPartial:

```
@{
var treeList = Html.DevExpress().TreeList(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "OrderTreeList";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "TreeList", Action = "OrderTreeListPartial" };

    settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewNodeRouteValues = new { Controller = "TreeList", Action = "OrderTreeListPartialAddNew" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateNodeRouteValues = new { Controller = "TreeList", Action = "OrderTreeListPartialUpdate" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteNodeRouteValues = new { Controller = "TreeList", Action = "OrderTreeListPartialDelete" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.NodeDragDropRouteValues = new { Controller = "TreeList", Action = "OrderTreeListPartialMove" };

    settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;

    settings.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    settings.KeyFieldName = "CustomerId";
    settings.ParentFieldName = "ParentId";
    settings.RootValue = 0;

    settings.Columns.Add(
column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "CustomerName";
    }
);
        settings.Columns.Add(
    column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "OrderDate";
    }
);       
        settings.Columns.Add(
column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "OrderTotal";
    column.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "{0:C}";
}
);
        settings.Columns.Add(
    column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "City";
    }
    );        



   settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsSelection.Enabled = true;
    });
    if (ViewData["EditError"] != null)
    {
        treeList.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }
}
@treeList.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

I think the problem is in my LINQ expression in my controller. The truth is I'm not an expert in LINQ and I'm evaluating the DevExpress extensions for a future project. Any help would be appreciated, wether in my LINQ or in how I prepared the TreeList.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify your problem but I think you shouldn't do the grouping in advance as this results in list of groups.

Just create a DataTable with the columns "CustomerId" and "ParentId".
The TreeList will then do the grouping